# SoapUI : : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to connect the Cosmo DB and query database through the Groovy script. However, I'm seeing the below exception Please help to resolve the issue

**Exception**

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target error at line: 52
```

***code***

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.*
import com.microsoft.azure.*
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.*
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.ConnectionPolicy;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DataType;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Database;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentCollection;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Index;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.IndexingPolicy;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RangeIndex;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RequestOptions;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.*
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.*



DocumentClient client;

// Get the database configuration
urlDB = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "envCosmoURL" );
keyDB = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "envCosmoKey" );

// Making the connection with COSMos DB account
client = new DocumentClient("${urlDB}",
                "${keyDB}",
                new ConnectionPolicy(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);

//Defining the options for retrieving data.
feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
feedOptions.setEmitVerboseTracesInQuery(false);

// In this section we are accessing to the studydefinition table
DB = client.queryDatabases(
        "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id='StudyDefinition'", null)
      .getQueryIterable()
      .toList();
 
StudyDefDB = DB[0]
```

Please help how to resolve the issue

Comment: Check if this urlDB certificate is expired

Comment: It has validity

Comment: 1) Are you using this at an employer that uses packet inspection for their security? 2) Are you running this from within SoapUI, or elsewhere? What version of SoapUI?